# Is it possible to control the volume of AVMIDIPlayer

Tags: ios, coremidi

I would like to use AVMIDIPlayer to play a multi-channel MIDI file in a game as background music, but I want to be able to fade out the background music when the game is over.  Unfortunately, AVMIDIPlayer does not have a volume parameter like AVAudioPlayer does.  Is there some way I can control the volume of AVMIDIPlayer?  (Changing the global volume is not really acceptable)

The only other solution I can see is to figure out how to identify the tracks in a MIDI file, create a multi-instrument AUGraph, and slap a mixer at the end.  I haven't been able to dig up any multi-instrument CoreMIDI examples, and it's looking pretty daunting.

Answer (score 0):

Use a MusicSequence to play with a low level core audio AUGraph, then play the sequence with a MusicPlayer. In the AUGraph you can control the mixer node.

[This](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/swift-augraph-and-musicsequence/) goes into excruciating detail.